# Inconsistency between the result of nested for loop and the independent function

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm making a loop for calculating the power of Hardy-Weinberg test for a variant called 'snp1' (with HWPower command, from HardyWeinberg package). This command needs the inputs n (sample size) and pA (minor allele frequency). I have to do the calculation many separate times with lots of ns and pAs, because they represent different population samples, so I did the first two manually, but now I want to make a for loop for all the others. 
I started with a simple loop with the first two, so I can easily check that the results are ok (and, thus, that the loop is working fine). But I encountered a problem when comparing the results of both calculations, which brings me to think that my code is not totally fine.

```
install.packages("HardyWeinberg")
library(HardyWeinberg)

snp1n=c(661,503)
snp1pA=c(0.006051,0.174)
HWpowersnp1<-numeric(2)

for(i in seq_along(snp1n)) {
  for(j in seq_along(snp1pA)) {
  HWpowersnp1[i]<-HWPower(n=snp1n[i],pA=snp1pA[j])
  }
}
HWpowersnp1
```

This gives me the following vector:

```
HWpowersnp1
[1] 0.04109278 0.04253145
```

But when I calculate each of them using the function alone, I get:

```
HWPower(n = 661,pA = 0.006051)
 [1] 0.02107572
HWPower(n = 503, nA = 175)
 [1] 0.04253145
```

I don't know where the problem is that is causing the inconsistence. It's strange because its only in the first result, not in the second (the second calculated power is ok, it gives me the same result, but the first one doesn't).

Comment: You are defining `HWpowersnp1<-numeric(2)` as an numeric array of size two, so you should get at the end of the loop two values. On the second invocation, it returns an scalar value as it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your double loop is wrong. If you run this

```
for(i in seq_along(snp1n)) {
  for(j in seq_along(snp1pA)) {
    print(paste(i,j))
    HWpowersnp1[i]<-HWPower(n=snp1n[i],pA=snp1pA[j])
  }
}
```

You will see that your function is running 4 times, not two like you expect. You want to iterate over `snp1n` and `snp1pA` simultaneously. So you should use `mapply` or `Map`. Try this instead

```
 HWpowersnp1 <- Map(HWPower, n=snp1n, pA=snp1pA)
```

Comment: Thank you! I now see that I misunderstood the usage of mapply, and that's why I didn't use it in the first place. Thank you very much! 
It's solved.